# Why is there such a huge performance difference between different kernel execution patterns in OpenCL?

Tags: performance, caching, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

My implementation executes 3 OpenCL kernels:

KernelA(), KernelB() and KernelC()

They all operate on the same data and kernel C depends on the Data, produced by A and B.

For evalutation, I executed A and B first, and then Kernel C multiple times on the same input data.

What I noticed: 
When I execute C repeadedly, it is very fast. 
It is like 3 times faster on the same data. (15ms vs 45 ms)

It is very interesting, as I can't explain this behaviour. 
There are no RAM-GPU memory transfers or anything.
Only global, constant and private memory are used.
The data is very big: Global work-group size is 640x480 and local work-group size is 32x2 (best result of brute force evaluation).

My GPUs are a Nvidia Quadro NVS 4200 and a Qualcom Adreno 430.

I can't explain this because of data caching, since the there is such a huge amount of workgroups executed on differen data. I also execute cl_flush() after each computation.
So why is there such a huge performance difference?

Comment: `I can't explain this because of data caching` Why not? If you repeatedly execute C, you'll obviously have less cache misses than A->B->C. Please clarify your question. Besides, a work group size of 32x2 is likely suboptimal on a desktop GPU.

Comment: The workgroup size is the best performing one, determined by bruteforcing all possible configurations. I rule out memory caching, because the work-group is executed thousand times per comutation with different data.

Answer (score 0):

`clFlush()` forces the commands to go to the GPU, but does not wait till they complete.
You should call `clFinish()` instead, before running the kernel C in order to ensure all the commands have finished.

Otherwise, kernel C is waiting for the GPU to finish the executions of kernels A and B.

Comment: Thanks. I just looked into my code, and I am using clFinish(). I confused these commands when posting the question.